# XML -How to get the display_value

Tags: xml, ms-access

How do we get the display_value in this node?

```
assigned_to display_value="GROUP">sampletext</assigned_to>
```

as my code `xNode.NodeValue` returns only this "`sampletext`"

sample code:

```
Public Sub LoadNodesIntoRs(ByRef nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList, rs AsADODB.Recordset, recordCount As Integer)

Dim xNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

Dim fieldIndex As Integer

For Each xNode In nodes
    If xNode.NodeType = NODE_TEXT Then

        Select Case xNode.ParentNode.nodeName
            Case "assigned_to"
                fieldIndex = 0

            Case "severity"
                fieldIndex = 1

            Case "urgency"
                fieldIndex = 2

        End Select

        rs(fieldIndex) = xNode.NodeValue


    End If

    If xNode.HasChildNodes Then
       'recurive call for the next node
      LoadNodesIntoRs xNode.ChildNodes, rs, recordCount
    End If

Next xNode

End Sub
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that "display_value" is not a node but an attribute.

```
xNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("display_value").Text
```

should get the value, see [Looping through XML using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020990/looping-through-xml-using-vba)

Comment: @gareching: Was this answer helpful? The game is to accept correct answers, so I suggest this to you. As I see you have asked two questions and haven't accepted any answer yet.