# How can I know whats my options (methods or property) for using on a node

Tags: vba, excel, xpath, methods

a small dummy question, sorry for that, I didn't found any reference about it.
How can I know whats is the options i got for variable 'el', 
i mean which method can i active on 'el' 
for example I know I can use method "getAttribute("....")", but what else which else method or property i can use ?

note: Ctrl + space won't work in this case. 
 i found this link 
but it's not relevant for vba 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757828(v=vs.85).aspx

VBA:

```
Dim oDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
Dim el As Object
Dim XML As String

XML =("C:\........")

oDoc.validateOnParse = True
oDoc.Load XML  


dim Name as String
Name= "yaron"


  'select the User node with Name="Yaron"
    Set el = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GetUserInfo/User[@Name='" & Name & "']")

'e. ???????whats my options?
    If Not el Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print el.getAttribute("LoginName")
Else
    Debug.Print "user id not found!"
End If
```

XML:

```
  <GetUserInfo>
           <User ID="16" Name="DAVID" LoginName="login1"/>
           <User ID="17" Name="GAL" LoginName="login2"/>
           <User ID="18" Name="YARON" LoginName="login3"/>
  </GetUserInfo>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but if the question is how can you get intellisense to show methods and properties of `el` then declare `el` explicitly as a node type (rather than an object).

Comment: [loop through the children of the `GetUserInfo` node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020990/looping-through-xml-using-vba)

Comment: @Ambie after declare el explicitly as a node type: "Dim el As node" i still can't see which method will work for el .. :/

Comment: Have a look at the answer from @TimWilliams. If you follow his declaration, then intellisense will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node can refer to different types of node objects, and these do not share a single set of properties/methods.

Try being more explicit in your variable type declaration, such as

```
Dim el As IXMLDOMElement
```

(check @ScottHoltzman's link)